# How to save cropped image to a directory with Jcrop using PHP

Tags: php, image, save, directory, jcrop

I can crop my images and click on crop. but then something goes wrong, because i don't know exactly how to save this image.

I use imagecreatefromjpeg from php.
this code look like this:

```
<?php
SESSION_start();
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
$targ_w = 200;
$targ_h = 400;
$jpeg_quality = 90;

$src = $_SESSION['target_path'];
$img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
$dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],
$targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);

//header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($dst_r, 'uploads/cropped/' . 'filename');

exit;
}

?>
```

My php code for saving the original image looks like this:

```
     <?php 
         session_start();
         $target = "uploads/"; 
         $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['filename']['name']) ; 
         $_SESSION['target_path'] = $target;

         $ok=1; 
         if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
         {
         echo "De afbeelding *". basename( $_FILES['filename']['name']). "* is geupload naar de map 'uploads'";
         } 
         else {
         echo "Sorry, er is een probleem met het uploaden van de afbeelding.";
         }
    ?>
```

how do i save the cropped image?
and is there a way to save the cropped image by overwriting the original so i get only the cropped image?

thanks in advance.

**EDIT: 
I can save 1 photo now. i edited my code to: 
    imagejpeg($dst_r, 'uploads/cropped/' . $filename .'boek.jpg');
But i have to make a function who can save multiple files with each another name. and maybe overwrite the original image, who is saved in 'uploads/'**

Comment: Does the folder you are trying to save to -- `uploads\cropped` -- exist?

Comment: Then you should probably add error checking to all your image function calls. imagecreatefromjpeg, imagecreatetruecolor, imagecopyresampled, and imagejpeg all return `false` on failure. If you do something like `if (! $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src)) die ('here is the problem');` with all your calls you'll find the problem soon enough.

Comment: but my code imagejpeg($dst_r, 'uploads/cropped/' . 'filename'); isn't right so hey uploads a file called filename now. but how do i call my image source so it uploads the image

Comment: Any other people who know how to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am going to reply to what seems to be the question now:

> But i have to make a function who can save multiple files with each
>   another name. and maybe overwrite the original image, who is saved in
>   'uploads/'

An easy method to do this would be to add the timestamp in the filename, this way everytime the operation is executed, you get a new filename. Doing something along the lines of:

```
imagejpeg($dst_r, 'uploads/cropped/' . $filename . time() . 'boek.jpg');
```

Will save a new image everytime.

When you want to overwrite the original, simply assign the right path

```
imagejpeg($dst_r, 'uploads/' . $filename .'.jpg');
```

**Edit:** What seems to be the problem is getting the right file name, without hardcoding 'boek.jpg'.

The original code posted used the string `filename` when saving the image

```
imagejpeg($dst_r, 'uploads/cropped/' . 'filename');
```

What you want to do, is deduce the filename from `$src`. To do so, simply use the function `basename` (documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)), so you will have:

```
imagejpeg($dst_r, 'uploads/cropped/' . basename($src)); // basename will already contain the extension
```

Comment: I will try this. it looks so easy :)

Comment: it saves the right image but with a name like this: 1354113593boek i actually want to have the original file called: boek1 overwrited to the new one. so i get no duplicated files.

Comment: I guess I didn't understood what you meant by `save multiple files with each another name`.  Let me rewrite this a bit...

Comment: This is exactly what i mean :D it works as a charm now! Thankyou!